# Autocomplete not working in Pycharm for Robot Framework

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I've installed PyCharm with the robotframework support plugin. The .robot files are identified successfully and I was able to create a simple script and run it in pyCharm.

However, my problem is that no keywords nor even the robotframework libraries (SeleniumLibrary) are recognized by pycharm in order to be autocompleted when typing them.

I also have the intellibot@seleniumlibrary patched plugin installed.

Is there something that I'm missing? Is there another configuration file somewhere?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TBFF.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the plugins itself. **TLDR** at the end, what follows is the state as of mid 2021.

---

Intellibot was a solid plugin, but abandoned 2016; the framework continued to develop & change, most notably with the SeleniumLibrary transforming from the old Selenium2Library. Then the "intellibot@seleniumlibrary patched" appeared, and it did work for that version *(somewhere around 2017, if I recall correctly)*. Yet the framework continued to change - what I mean by that is the way a library plugs in, which is the main trouble for "RobotFramework support" and a few other plugins.
But also PyCharm evolved, eventually making the Intellibot & derivatives not working but for the simplest libraries *(and throwing Java exceptions at a steady rate)*.
And the plugins continue to be abandoned,with no development; leading to a state where cases development in PyCharm is a mixed bag *(of frustration)*.

---

### Hope is not lost!

There is a fork by the github user lte2000 that is actively developed:

https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot

That person has managed to fix most of the annoyances of the original library; covered solid support for the SeleniumLibrary *(which IMHO is one of the most complex out there)*; and added new features - support for the new IF...ELSE syntax, FOR loops, etc.

The plugin is called "[IntelliBot #patched](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17424-intellibot-patched)" in JetBrains Marketplace.